# Dualizing sheaf of nodal genus two curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I'm interested in extending Riemann-Roch and Serre duality to bundles or sheaves defined on nodal curves.  The extension of Riemann-Roch I think is straightforward: simply replace the geometric genus by the arithmetic genus.  Unless I'm mistaken, Serre duality can be extended to nodal curves by replacing the canonical bundle with the *dualizing sheaf*.  I've never worked with a dualizing sheaf concretely, so I was hoping someone could help me in one very explicit example.

Let $C$ be the nodal curve given as the glueing of two elliptic curves at their origins.  One can think of this as a particular kind of genus two curve.  Obviously, the normalization is just the two disjoint elliptic curves.  But what exactly is the dualizing sheaf $\omega_{C}$ and how does one carry out the computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, simple nodal curves are locally planar and so the dualizing sheaf is a line bundle. So, if the elliptic curves are $E_1,E_2$, one has an exact sequence $0\to \mathcal{O}_C\to \mathcal{O}_{E_1}\oplus\mathcal{O}_{E_2}\to k(p)\to 0$, where $p$ is the origin. Dulaizing, you get, $0\to\mathcal{O}_{E_1}\oplus\mathcal{O}_{E_2}\to \omega_C\to k(p)\to 0$. Most calculations you need can be made using this sequence.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.  For an example calculation, let's say I wanted to compute the first Chern class of $\omega_{C}$.  Using your exact sequence, I seem to get $c_{1}(\omega_{C})=0$, by the additivity of $c_{1}$ on SES.  Is this right?  I'm a little unsure if by $\mathcal{O}_{E_{1}} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{E_{2}}$ you really mean some pushforward.  So maybe my argument is flawed.

Comment: Chern class is computed where? For a good theory for non-irreducible varieties, these are not numbers anymore. For a baby case, think of two disjoint curves, then Chern class is a pair of numbers. $\mathcal{O}_{E_i}$ are  quotients of $\mathcal{O}_X$ and thus sheaves on $X$.

Comment: I see, I guess I just naively tried to apply $c_{1}$ to the short exact sequence you gave.  Is there a notion of the "degree of $\omega_{C}$" analogous to that on a smooth curve?  In applying Serre duality to a Riemann-Roch computation, I would hope to argue something like $h^{0}(C, L^{\vee} \otimes \omega_{C})=0$ if the degree of $L^{\vee} \otimes \omega_{C}$ is negative, or something.

Comment: Degree makes perfect sense for line bundles, if you think of it as "total degree". In the above,  $\deg \omega_C=2$. One way of defining it is of course (as Mumford does it) for a line bundle $L$ on a projective curve $X$, $\deg L=\chi(L)-\chi(\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Comment: Am I correct to say that if we added a third elliptic curve glued nodally to one of the previous two, we would get $\text{deg}\omega_{C}=4$?  And if you added yet another you would get degree 6 I believe.

Comment: "Adding" third curve can be problematic. In general, the new curve is no longer planar and $\omega_C$ is no longer a line bundle. So, care must be taken with familiar notions.

Comment: @Mohan: I don't think you dualized correctly. For a correct computation you can embed $C$ into the surface $S = E_1 \times E_2$ as the coordinate cross. Then by adjunction $\omega_C \cong O_S(E_1 + E_2)\vert_C$, and this sheaf is a bit different from your answer.

Comment: @Sasha There can not be two dualizing sheaves.